# None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting the error below when I connect the iPhone to my PC and try to run the application from Xcode.  Where as in emulator I am able to run the application without any problem.

```
Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices:
iPhone
```

[image: Screenshot for error]

What could be the issue? I already found the answer here [None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585821/none-of-the-valid-provisioning-profiles-include-the-devices) but confused that's the same issue as mine.  I am newbie to IOS.

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006773/xcode6-error-no-matching-provisioning-profiles-found-for-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup profile in `Build Settings` of your project. Make a new profile after adding `UDID` of your iPhone on [Developer Member Centre](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action) (If you haven't added it already).

Please refer [Maintaining Identifiers, Devices, and Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html) if you want to go through whole process of Managing Provisioning Profile

If you want to Add Device ID in existing `Provisioning Profile`, follow these steps:

1. Go to Member Centre
2. Select your Provisioning Profile
3. Press Edit
4. Click on CheckBox with appropriate device name under devices Tab.

After performing above steps, download `Updated Provisioning Profile`, but before installing it, delete `Old Provisioning Profile`.

Comment: Actually the application is already submitted on app store but not by me, right now I am doing some modification and and need to resubmit. So at developer center the provisioning profile already there I may need to edit it to add new device is it possible?.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please review it, hope it helps you now.

Comment: Yes I understand, one more question, is there any way to find which provisioning profile used for a specific project from Xcode,  actually I checked at the Member Center  I can see many profile there, just confused which one used for the project,  as the project developed by some other person.

Comment: Yes you can find it out by clicking at `Provisioning Profile` at Member Centre, then by viewing its `App ID`, select one which matches `Bundle Identifier` of your Application in Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

It means that the provisioning profile does not contain device id of the phone you are trying to run the app on.  The other answer you mention looks like the correct way of solving it (Go to developer.apple.com and register your iPhone there then include the device id in the provisioning profile and finally refresh profiles in XCode). Anyway code signing is most annoying thing i find in doing iOS apps.