# Can't Access Certificates, Identifiers & profiles within developer.apple.com

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate

Im trying to follow the following [None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585821/none-of-the-valid-provisioning-profiles-include-the-devices) as I'm trying to run an application on my iPhone 5 and getting the error "No matching provisioning profiles found". which is odd as it runs on my iPhone 6 fine...

when i log into developer.apple.com and click on 'Certificates, IDs & Profiles'  it takes me to 'https://developer.apple.com/account/#/welcome' where it doesn't give me any option to add a device as all i can see is:

[image]

Is there another way of fixing the error?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?? I was earlier invited for developer role and now I am getting the same issue described above. Let me know if you have found the solution. :)

Answer (score 57):

> **Note :** As per the new rules (2019)

After a long research & contacting to the Apple team its getting more cleared Now.

Lots of developers thinking earlier when we were giving Admin access of the Developer account, We were able to access the ***Certificates & Provisioning Profiles***. Why this option is disabled now ?

**So here is the new Rules defined by Apple :**

1. As per new rules if you have **Individual Account** than you would not be able to provide the Access of ***Certificates & Provisioning Profiles*** to the other Users.
2. Even if you are giving Admin access to any user they will not be able to access the Certificates & Provisioning Profiles.
3. If you have taken **Enterprise account**, than the option will be open for you to give access of certificates & Provisioning profiles to the other developers.

**New Edition :**

- Suppose if you have a Individual Account & still you want your developer to access the Certificates & Provisioning Profiles ? Than you can contact the Apple Support team & send request for the same. If they will look the request suitable than they will help to give your Developer access of the Certificates & Provisioning Profile.

Hope this clear all doubts & helps to everyone.

Comment: I was searching the same thing since one month as I was not able to give access of certificates to other developers through my individual account. Finally I updated my account to Enterprise. It works now. Really helpful answer and up to date. Thanks

Comment: @saxenarishav 1 more option I found in recent days I am updating my answer

Comment: That option is coming only for Enterprise account bro. Thats very old answer

Comment: "As per new rules if you have Individual Account...." could you please provide quote from the rules or link? Can't find it.

Comment: I originally came to this page because I was trying to regenerate my provisioning profile (with certificates) without a Developer account, just an Apple Id. So far without that menu there's no way of accomplishing that?

Comment: @jeancallisti yeah there is no other option then that

Comment: Enterprise accounts cannot publish on the AppStore and are meant for in-house publishing. I doubt that you cannot give access to Certificates & Provisioning Profiles when you publish on the AppStore.

Answer (score 42):

If you have paid Apple Developer program and lost access to certificates, ID & profile, your admin or account owner can go to developer portal, under **Peoples** option tap on the specific user and check mark Access to **Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles** under **Developer resources**. See below.

[image]

Comment: The 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles' option does not show up in the apple developer menu immediately. Is there a lag of some sort?

Comment: Ah yes. It took 10 minutes before it 'kicked in'

Comment: All admins at our company account have this option greyed out. And our account owner is away. Does anyone has this situation?

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko it's not just you as I was recently invited to an account where that option is greyed out as well and I'm not able to gain the typical certificate access.

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko Did you get any solution for the greyed out option

Comment: @hardiksa for me only solution was to contact with account owner and ask him to give me permissions

Comment: This one is weird because I am the account owner and I can't give this permission to anyone now?

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko We found ou that this checkbox is disabled for Admins, App Managers and Developers if the account type is 'Individual' instead of 'Organization'.

Comment: what if the individual account holder has enrolled in the program but a team member was added via email and they are trying to access developer resources?

Answer (score 12):

Being a registered Apple developer gives you access to a lot of information, but to be able to send apps to the App Store (and Create and manage certificates) you need to enroll in Apple’s iOS developer program. This is the part that will cost you US$99 per year.

For more info [go to this link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1)

But you can able to run on any device With Xcode 7 you are no longer required to have a developer account in order to test your apps on your device

[check here...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4952845/4205077)

Comment: Ah i see. How can i run my app on my iPhone 5 without adding it as  device? I have been able to do it with other devices however for some reason on this device i get the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not yet enrolled as apple developer.

Just you need to enrol as apple developer for personal or organisation.

Step 1: Go to this link [Apple Developer Console](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/)

Step 2: Login with your apple id, if don't have create new one then login.

Step 3: Press the enroll button present in the top-right corner.

Step 4: Read the and agree the terms to proceed.

Step 5: Select the one from which you want to enroll either personal or organisation.

Step 6: Then select your payment option, then pay.

Step 7: Finally now you are a developer after completing all the steps, now you can find certificates tab in your account page.

Answer (score -2):

You need to enroll in the apple developer program if you or your organization hasn't already: https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/