# Unable to fix code signing issue: Xcode7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile, xcode7.3

I am trying to run my application on different devices for testing purposes. It successfully allows me to run the app on iPhone4S, iPhone6 & iPhone6S. I tried to run it on my iPhone 5 however I am getting the following error:

```
"Failed to code sign. None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices "DEVICE NAME". Xcode can attempt to fix this"
```

When I click "Fix Issue" I get the following:

```
"Unable to fix code signing issue" "Xcode failed to resolve this issue. Check your code signing setting; ensure you have matching signing certificates and provisioning profiles installed and try again".
```

I have tried following various answers such as [None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585821/none-of-the-valid-provisioning-profiles-include-the-devices) however I am using a free account and as a result i don't have access to the devices portal on developer.apple.com.

How can I fix this error without adding a device on the develop portal? Its odd that I only have this issue on this device.

Any help would be appreciated

P.s. I am using Xcode 7.3

UPDATE:

My apple ID looks like the below:

[image]

Comment: you must have a developer account to access developer.apple.com.

Comment: @AbhinandanPratap I do, just not a paid one which is required to access the 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles' section

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **PRODUCT click Profile**! It will resolve your issue or just go for **build for profiling.**

Comment: Im still getting the same error "No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices xxxx"

Comment: Okay then go to Xcode in toolbar above and click preferences. Click accounts and add your apple account(free one ). If it is already there remove it and add it again. at last close and reopen xcode

Comment: Oh my god .. It must be something silly but something very critical and we are ignoring it. meanwhile i will search and give u the answer

Comment: I emailed developer support and finally found the reason... The free developer account has a restriction of 3 devices per account!

Comment: @jessMurray : yes exactly !! we missed this small thing! anyway all d best keep coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

firstly you have to Make sure you have a valid apple developer account then you have access to developer.apple.com and generate profiles for your app.

for more please check i hope it will solve your issues :

[Xcode 7 error: "Missing iOS Distribution signing identity for ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821189/xcode-7-error-missing-ios-distribution-signing-identity-for?rq=1)

Comment: I have a valid free developer account. As I haven't paid for the account i can't access the 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles' within the developer.apple.com

Comment: I tried the link you provided however still experiencing the same error message

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Developer account, make sure that the device on which you are trying to install the build is registered in your Developer account and Provisioning profile. Otherwise Xcode won't let you install the build in there.

Comment: I'm using a free developer account. How can i check if the device is registered without checking at 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profile'

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on the number of devices that we can test our app using a free developer account. I tested my app on 5 devices, and all are working. But the only catch is that the provisioning profiles expire in 7 days, so the app does not not work after 7 days unless we re-launch it from XCode. The code signing issue could be due to some other issue. But I still dont understand why someone from the apple team told you that the limit is 3 devices.

More info on that - [Is there a limit on the number of devices on which we can launch our app using the free apple developer account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37844344/is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-devices-on-which-we-can-launch-our-app-using-t)