# Unable to fix code signing issue error in Xcode

Tags: swift2, xcode7.3

I am trying to launch my app on an i-pad.

I have connected my iPad to Mac and then ran the solution. I got an error saying "Failed to code sign "myAppName". None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices: "myDeviceName". Xcode can attempt to fix this issue. This will reset your code signing and provisioning settings to recommended values and resolve issues with signing identities and provisioning profiles." with a fix issue button.

Upon clicking the fix issue button, I got another error saying - "Unable to fix code signing issue. Xcode failed to resolve the issue. Check your code signing settings; ensure you have a matching signing certificate and provisioning profile installed; and try again."

Then I tried to click on fix-issue in the Xcode->Project->General Window.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT3gR.png)

But then got another error msg saying - "The 'In-App Purchase' feature is only available to users enrolled in Apple Developer Program. Please visit 
developer.apple.com/programs/ to enroll."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhPGi.png)

I do not need in-app purchasing, but still I am not able to disable it. 
I have been stuck with this issue since few days, not able to find a workaround.

I tried revoking my apple certificate, deleting all the existing profiles and downloading them again, but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: (1) select your target -> Capabilities and check if In-App purchase is disabled (2) do you have the same trouble with another iOS device?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.. I tried (1) In-App purchase is enabled by default. I am not able to disable it. (2) I faced this issue initially with another device, but then it suddenly started working. Not sure why..

Comment: "...I am not able to disable it ...". so something is wrong :-). try to clean the project, restart Xcode and next open the project again. sometimes the Xcode is ... how to say it ... If this will not help, create a new project and try to simulate the same behavior in 'clean' environment. did you edit your .plist file manually before?

Comment: I tried cleaning the project, restarting XCode, but it didn't work. Then I tried it on another device that I had already installed the app on, it started working. So my question is - Is there any limit on the number of devices that we can test our app on?? P.S - I am using the free account.

Comment: NO, there is no limit, but all your devices must be authorized. so, try it again with the 'defected' device and go to Devices and approve your device. by the way, with free apple id you can not use some capabilities (generally the capabilities which need add entitlements)

Comment: Since I dont have a paid account, I am not able to check on the registered devices from the developer page. I will try once again with the defected device and update.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937150/unable-to-fix-code-signing-issue-xcode7-3 -> The second to last comment in 1st answer says that we can launch our app only three devices, so I thought this could be the issue.. Can you confirm that we can launch our device on more than 3 devices, coz I couldn't find any info regarding this on their page...

Comment: yes, i used to use more than 10 devices ... check your device in XCode, Window->Devices (while your device is connected), not on apple site

Comment: I went to Xcode, Windows->Devices, what do you mean by "approve your device" ? Did you have a free account or a paid apple account? Thanks for all your help..

Comment: connect your trouble-making device, windows->devices .. click on the device and if the device is not correctly recognized, Xcode will do the rest for you. at first, isolate your trouble in some simple project with default project settings

Comment: I created a simple helloWorld app and successfully launched it on one iPad. But when I try to run the app on the "defected iPad", I get error msg - "Failed to code sign "helloWorld" Xcode can attempt to fix this issue. This will reset ..." along with a fix issue button. Upon clicking the fix-issue I get - "Unable to fix code signing issue. XCode failed to resolve the issue. Check your code signing settings ... n try again" Not able to run the helloWorld app on this defected Ipad.. P.S this iPad was recently updated from iOS 8 to iOS 9.3.2. (All the other iPads that I am testing are iOS 9.3.1)