# Is there a limit on the number of devices on which we can launch our app using the free apple developer account?

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7.3

Is there a limit on the number of devices on which we can launch our app using the free apple developer account?

I am using Xcode 7.3 and iOS 9.3.2
I am able to launch my app on few devices, but I always get code signing issue when I try to launch it on another new device. I tried checking the apple developer page, but could not find info regarding this.

Comment: Please don't tell me you are trying to implement a "Brick and Mortar App Store" :-)

Comment: No published limit to # of devices. Please post more details about the code signing issue if you'd like more help resolving that.

Comment: How are you trying to launch it? Plug device into your Mac and run it, does that work?

Comment: @gnasher729 - yes just plugging in the iPad to my Mac and running it will create an app on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of devices you can build on with a free account. (At least, there is no published limit.)

As a side note for future readers of this question, there is a published [list of restrictions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SupportedCapabilities/SupportedCapabilities.html). Using only the free Apple account, your app will not be able to use these features:

- Apple Pay
- Associated Domains
- Game Center
- iCloud: CloudKit
- iCloud: iCloud Documents
- iCloud: Key-Value Storage
- In-App Purchase
- Personal VPN
- Push Notifications
- Wallet

Comment: the same Apple ID is not required. (tested with my family members)

Comment: The provisioned app works only for a week. Is there any way we can increase that time line?

Comment: I created a simple helloWorld app and tried to run it on a 4th device and it is working successfully. (I am saying this because I read in some post that the limit is 3 devices)